# NSCache is returning null after restarting project

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscache

I'm working with `NSCache` in Objective-C and Cocoa for iOS. Every time I restart the project, the `getCacheRecommend` call returns `null` and I expect it to return a value.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class ASJsonDiscoverModel;
@interface ASUserCache : NSObject

+ (ASUserCache *)sharedInstance;    
- (void)clear;
- (void)setCacheRecommend:(ASJsonDiscoverModel *)discover;
- (ASJsonDiscoverModel *)getCacheRecommend;
```

`ASJsonDiscoverModel` is my custom object class.

```
#import "ASUserCache.h"
@interface ASUserCache ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSCache *cache;
@end

@implementation ASUserCache

+ (ASUserCache *)sharedInstance
{
    __strong static ASUserCache *cache = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cache = [[ASUserCache alloc] init];
    });
    return cache;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
         _cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCacheRecommend:(ASJsonDiscoverModel *)discover
{
    NSString *key = @"channelRecommend";
    [_cache removeObjectForKey:key];
    [_cache setObject:discover forKey:key];
}

- (ASJsonDiscoverModel *)getCacheRecommend
{
    NSString *key = @"channelRecommend";
    return [_cache objectForKey:key];
}

- (void)clear
{
    if (_cache) {
        [_cache removeAllObjects];
    }
}

- (NSString *)keyforUserID:(NSString *)userID
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"**%@",userID];
}
```

Comment: Code looks OK to me.  Please show more code, demonstrating the issue.

Comment: well NSCache doesn't persist stuff to disk -- do you want it to?

Comment: when the project is running,[[ASUserCache sharedInstance] getCacheRecommend] returns a result.but everytime i restart the project,it return nil.

Comment: It's an in-memory cache. It will also eject objects during periods of high memory consumption.

Comment: but not in high memory.it returns nil everytime i restart it.